# Serialize a Perl package variable and update once every 24 hours from a CGI script

Tags: perl, serialization, hash, persistence

I am not too experienced with Perl, but I am trying to achieve something that sounds relatively reasonable and simple.

I want to create a package variable hash that is serialized somewhere and updates once every 24 hours. Basically a cache of data from an external service for the day. I tried the following to test:

```
our %hashMap;

sub updateMap {
    my $mapSize = scalar(keys %hashMap);
    if ($mapSize == 0) {
        populateMap();
    }

    return \%hashMap;
}
```

I added some logging statements and see that every time I call updateMap, the map size is always 0 so it always re-populates the map. The problem is that this is a CGI script so nothing persists.

How can I get the value of the map to stick between function calls and how can I update this map once every 24 hours? One option I have in mind is using Storable store/retrieve to save the hash to a file and retrieve later. Is it possible to check when a file was last modified in Perl to determine if 24 hours have passed?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the code of populateMap and what package all of this code is in. Did you mean to return a different variable (`%nodeMap`)? Are you operating in the same package? (`our %hashMap` just makes `%hashMap` in that scope an alias to `%<current package>::hashMap`)

Comment: Would also need some more information for the "every 24 hours" question. Is this a persistently running script?

Comment: @Grinnz I want to access the map from other packages. "populateMap" makes an external service call that populates the map. I only want to make this call once a day, but I want other packages to be able to access this data repeatedly after it has been loaded.

Comment: From another package, just fully qualify the variable name with the package name, rather than using an `our` alias. But it's a better idea in the long run to instead use a lexical (`my`) variable, and write subroutines to access it as needed externally.

Comment: @Grinnz thank you. I tried that, but the values never stick. I apologize for not adding this context sooner, but it may have to do with how I am accessing the package that contains the has. It is being accessed by a CGI script. I suspect whenever this CGI script calls a subroutine in the package that creates the hash, it creates a new "instance".

Comment: A CGI script is not a persistent process. Variables only exist while the process is running. So in that sense every request creates a new instance.

Comment: Two very different solutions to being able to cache between requests would be 1) convert to a modern framework which can be run as a persistent daemon that can keep state in memory, or 2) use a database to share state between requests, even a simple one like SQLite or Redis (preferred as it works regardless of deployment strategy). Either approach would probably be beyond the scope of the current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few questions here, on how to set this up and on update/persistence.

A simple and good way to organize this is to have a module for your "map," with subs that provide access, updating, saving/loading, and whatever else may be useful.

One way to keep data up-to-date is to check every time the user code retrieves the "map" from the module, for instance by checking the timestamp on the file in which data is serialized.  (Other ways are mentioned at the end.)

The module

```
package MapService;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say state);
use Data::Dump qw(dd pp);

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(get_map force_update save_to_file);

use Storable qw(nstore retrieve);  # consider locking versions

my $data_file = 'data.storable';
    
my %map;

my $_populate_map = sub { 
    # use "external service" call to populate (update)
    state $cnt = 1;
    %map = ( a => 1, b => 2, cnt => $cnt++ );
    save_to_file();
};

if (-f $data_file) {                         # initialize
    %map = %{ load_from_file($data_file) };
}
else {
    $_populate_map->();
    save_to_file();
}

my $_update_map = sub {
    my $filename = $_[0] // $data_file;     #/
    if (-M $data_file >= 1)  {              # one+ day old
        $_populate_map->();
        save_to_file(file => $filename);
    }   
};

sub update_map { $_update_map->(@_) };  # outside use, if supported

sub get_map {                           # use this call to check/update
    $_update_map->(@_);
    return \%map;
};

sub save_to_file {
    my %opts = @_; 
    my $file = $opts{file} // $data_file;
    my $map  = $opts{map}  // \%map;
    nstore $map, $file;
}

sub load_from_file {
    my $filename = $_[0] // $data_file;
    return retrieve $filename;
}
    
sub force_update { $_populate_map->() }   # for tests

1;
```

with the test driver

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say'; 
use Data::Dump qw(dd);

use MapService qw(get_map force_update save_to_file);

my $map = get_map();
dd $map;

force_update() for 1..2;   # to force more changes in "map"
dd get_map();

save_to_file();  # perhaps in END block
```

Repeated runs, and examination of the data file, confirm persistence and data manipulations. Little tweaks in the driver help as well, or add routines to change data at will for nicer testing.

Notes

- `save_to_file` is called often to update timestamp, for checks later in the same run
- There's some corner-cutting and silly choices in the module, for brevity
- Lexical coderefs (`$_populate_map` and `$_update_map`) are for module's internal use, not seen from outside,<sup>†</sup> to which outside access can be given like it is with `update_map`
- `Storable` is always a solid choice, but there are other options.  A distinct disadvantage of this module is that the data must be both written and read with it (and even module versions shouldn't differ much); advantages are that it takes nearly any valid Perl data and is fast

  In particular consider `JSON` and `YAML`, the widely used formats that work across languages (and are readable). If your data is simple enough I'd definitely recommend these
- We are told that this is for a legacy system without many tools, perhaps not even `cron`
- Consider using locks for any work with serialized data here
- This is a stub for realistic arrangements, and even as it stands it needs error handling added

The query from the title of this question, about how to run this once every day and keep data, is addressed above in a very simple way. How to actually do it depends on the rest of the project, and there sure are other ways.

The check of whether data needs updating is done as data is pulled from the module by `get_map`, so in between such calls we may have missed the need to update; if data is loaded by the caller just once (at start) we never check during the run.

One way around this is to compute the remaining time until update when the program starts, then `fork` another process and `sleep` in it for that duration, then run the update and send a signal.  The main script can then update its "map" data in the signal handler.

Another way would be to set up an event loop for the timer but that is likely an overkill (and which would raise the overall complexity a lot).

---

<sup>†</sup> Contrary to the mantra of how "there are no private methods" in Perl, a function given via a lexical (`my`) code reference cannot be seen from outside the module, since lexical variables don't exist outside their scope, and thus is truly and fully "private" to the module.

This has serious limitations for systemic use in object oriented design and in that sense there are indeed no (good) private *methods*, but it is possible to have internal functions, inaccessible from outside, and this is used for restricted (internal) purposes.

Comment: Thank you. The script does not run persistently, it is a CGI script. I think a potential solution is using freeze/thaw to serialize the data to a file and then deserialize when needed.

Comment: @Seephor OK, thank you for clarification -- precisely, freeze/thaw is one way to do that.  There are yet others, depending on details.

Comment: @Seephor Then you can also consider a separate program, dedicated to just updadting the map, which can then nicely be run once a day by cron (so by the system).   Then the module needs to check for race conditions (is data being updated _right_ now?) whenever it loads the map, for example using locks. And the program should probably load the map from file every time it needs it, so to not miss an update ... so this gets a little more complicated, but at least timing is done by the system.

Comment: @Seephor I'll try to update to your clarifications as I get to it, so if there are further worthy details please add. You can also update the question itself

Comment: I updated the question with more clarification and one approach I have in mind. A cron job sounds ideal, but the environment I am working in requires adding some more dependencies to have it deployed alongside this application. Basically a legacy system that is on the way out, but needs to fetch this particular data from a new source for compliance/migration reasons. So while do-able, I would prefer something that can run within this application to limit scope of effort.

Comment: @Seephor Updated.  Given the complexity of what you ask this is a sketch (which works in my tests)

Comment: "advantages are that it takes any valid Perl data and is fast" - Not quite. It can't serialize file handles, code references (without ugly magic), or a few other esoteric types of references. It can't serialize regexp references until recent Perls. The serialization format is also not always portable between versions of Perl. For these reasons and because it's faster, I usually recommend [Sereal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sereal) (it also doesn't serialize coderefs/handles, but it does do regexp refs).

Comment: @Grinnz  I took the serialization part as more of a side-note in this topic, and said "_there are other_" expecting readers to look it up. Still: (1) by "_Perl **data**_" I meant things within a reason, surely not file handles and exotic things (added "_nearly_")  (2) I warn of portability (it has to be this module) and expect users to investigate (added a note).   There are far more serious (and interesting) concerns here, I think. The choice of serialization is one clean part of it. Thank you for mentioning `Sereal`, which is recommended often.

Comment: +1 thank you. I went this approach and used the same pattern of whenever a call is made to retrieve the map it checks if the file exists and if it is less than a day old otherwise it will create/re-populate the map.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds you like need a cache with an expiration date.  I'd start with [CHI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CHI).  As you need a cache that survives beyond the lifetime of your process, the simplest driver to use is [CHI::Driver::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/CHI::Driver::File).  Here's some sample code which sets a 1 second expiration on the cache and queries it at random intervals to show that the expiration works.

```
use feature 'say';
use strict;
use warnings;

use CHI;

use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;
use Time::HiRes qw[ usleep ];

sub populateMap {
    my $date = localtime->datetime;
    say "Put: $date";
    return { date => $date};
}

sub updateMap {
    my $cache = CHI->new(
                         driver         => 'File',
                         root_dir       => 'cache',
                        );

    my $data = $cache->get( 'key' );
    if ( ! defined $data ) {
        $data = populateMap ();
        $cache->set( 'key', $data, '1 second' );
    }
    return $data;
}

my $data = updateMap();

for (0..10){
    my $sleep = 0.75e6 * rand() + 0.25e6;
    say sprintf "\nSleep: %.2f seconds", $sleep / 1e6;
    usleep $sleep;
    say "Got:", updateMap()->{date};
}
```

And some sample output:

```
% perl cache.pl
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:05

Sleep: 0.97 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:06
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:06

Sleep: 0.83 seconds
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:06

Sleep: 0.49 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:07
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:07

Sleep: 0.88 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:08
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:08

Sleep: 0.75 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:09
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:09

Sleep: 0.28 seconds
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:09

Sleep: 0.60 seconds
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:09

Sleep: 0.34 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:10
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:10

Sleep: 0.80 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:11
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:11

Sleep: 0.63 seconds
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:11

Sleep: 0.95 seconds
Put: 2019-06-05T09:42:12
Got:2019-06-05T09:42:12
```

Notes:

- While the example is a single process, the underlying mechanism will survive the lifetime of the process.
- [CHI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CHI) provides a *key-value* store, so you need to create a key.  I chose the string `key`.